# Rescue data on (dropped) external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, ddrescue

Recently I dropped my 4TB hard drive.

When I connect it to my Mac, the disk utility recognizes it but is unable to initialize it.

I ran [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) on it. The log says that all data is "unreadable".

Is there another option I could try to rescue my data besides bringing it to a local PC store? Or is my drive most likely not recoverable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: Welcome to SU! If the hardware is damaged you can't solve the issue via software. You will need a specialized data recovery company.

Comment: Unfortunate, I'm afraid that @Andrea is right. Dropping a mechanical hard drive almost always damages an important piece of hardware inside. This is pretty bad because a third-party data recovery tool can rarely work and it could potentially do more harm than good when it comes to your data. I'd strongly recommend you turn to a professional data recovery company for assistance. They would be your best bet on getting any of your files back. :( Either way, doing data retrieving attempts by yourself is very dangerous when the drive is physically corrupted. Best of luck! Hope this helps.